# python mechanize to access Sharepoint website

Tags: python, mechanize

I'm trying to access Sharepoint using mechanize but i got a 401 error. Here's the code i'm using:

```
import mechanize

url = "http://sharepoint:8080/foo/bar/foobar.aspx"

br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/4.0(compatible; MSIE 7.0b; Windows NT 6.0)')]
br.add_password(url, 'domain\\user', 'myPassword')
r = br.open(url)
html = r.read()
```

Did i miss anything?

Answer (score 1):

Did you happen to try [Python Ntlm](http://code.google.com/p/python-ntlm/) for accessing SharePoint?

Examples in the Ntlm doc will explain how to use it with Urllib2. Pasted below the code for using NTLM authentication using mechanize.

```
import mechanize
from ntlm import HTTPNtlmAuthHandler
pass_manager = mechanize.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, url, user, password)
auth_NTLM = HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.HTTPNtlmAuthHandler(pass_manager)

browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.add_handler(auth_NTLM)

r = browser.open(url)
html = r.read()
```

Comment: I tried it and i got AttributeError: HTTPResponse instance has no attribute '__iter__'. Any idea?

Comment: This question is super old, but for ease of use, I'll link the fix for the __iter__ issue.
Essentially it's a bug in Mechanize and you need to patch it yourself.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/14726708/269297

There is a pull request open on Mechanize but not much is happening with it: 

https://github.com/jjlee/mechanize/issues/88

Comment: And for what it's worth, once I applied the fix, the above worked like a charm. So thanks @Pravin.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/4.0(compatible; MSIE 7.0b; Windows NT 6.0)'), ('Authorization', 'Basic %s:%s' % ('domain\\user', 'myPassword'))]
```

instead of

```
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/4.0(compatible; MSIE 7.0b; Windows NT 6.0)')]
```

This should work if your sharepoint server provides Basic Auth.

Comment: I got the Attribute error: AttributeError: mechanize._mechanize.Browser instance has no attribute addHeader
 (perhaps you forgot to .select_form()?)

Comment: i edited the answer - in the first case i just wrote it without testing for syntax errors - sorry :D

Comment: No worries but even after changing the codes, i'm still getting 401 error.

Comment: when you access your URL (http://sharepoint:8080/foo/bar/foobar.aspx) - do you see a web form or it pops up a window for requesting your credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the usage in the [mechanize docs](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) you only need to specify the username (eg `'john_doe'`, try this

```
...
br.add_password(url, 'username_string', 'myPassword')
r = br.open(url)
html = r.get_data() # r.get_data() can be called many times without calling seek
```