# Python mechanize with NTLM getting AttributeError: HTTPResponse instance has no attribute '__iter__'

Tags: python, mechanize, ntlm

I am trying to access a site that's secured with NTLM authentication using python-ntlm and mechanize but I am getting this error.

```
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 203, in open
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 249, in _mech_open
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 304, in _set_response
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/mechanize/_response.py", line 521, in upgrade_response
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/mechanize/_response.py", line 338, in __init__
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/mechanize/_response.py", line 353, in _set_fp
AttributeError: HTTPResponse instance has no attribute '__iter__'
```

I am able to get a proper response when I use the urllib2 library. But for some reason, it fails when I try to access it using mechanize.

This is the code I have.

```
import urllib2
from ntlm import HTTPNtlmAuthHandler

user = '<myusername>'
password = "<mypass>"
url = "https://somesite.com"

passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, url, user, password)
# create the NTLM authentication handler
auth_NTLM = HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.HTTPNtlmAuthHandler(passman)

import mechanize
browser = mechanize.Browser()
handlersToKeep = []

for handler in browser.handlers:
    if not isinstance(handler,
    (mechanize._http.HTTPRobotRulesProcessor)):
        handlersToKeep.append(handler)

browser.handlers = handlersToKeep
browser.add_handler(auth_NTLM)

response = browser.open(url)
print(response.read())
```

Does anyone has any idea what's going on? Am I doing something wrongly here?

Comment: ... this seems to be the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225475/python-with-mechanize-and-ntlm

Comment: And by the way thaks for the code you used. It would have taken me ages to work out how to use NTLM with mechanize :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I patched mechanize to work around this:

```
--- _response.py.old    2013-02-06 11:14:33.208385467 +0100
+++ _response.py    2013-02-06 11:21:41.884081708 +0100
@@ -350,8 +350,13 @@
             self.fileno = self.fp.fileno
         else:
             self.fileno = lambda: None
-        self.__iter__ = self.fp.__iter__
-        self.next = self.fp.next
+
+        if hasattr(self.fp, "__iter__"):
+            self.__iter__ = self.fp.__iter__
+            self.next = self.fp.next
+        else:
+            self.__iter__ = lambda self: self
+            self.next = lambda self: self.fp.readline()

     def __repr__(self):
         return '<%s at %s whose fp = %r>' % (
```

Comment: hmm...is this patch merged already? Or do I have to change the file myself to work around this?

Comment: No it's not, I only patched it locally.

Comment: I ran into this exact same problem a couple of days ago. I applied your fix and everything worked fine. I have also opened https://github.com/jjlee/mechanize/issues/88 with mechanize and opened a pull request for it. I have linked back to this issue and credited cube with the fix.

Comment: Thanks :-) Do you think it will get merged? Mechanize seemed pretty dead to me last time I was checking.

Comment: https://github.com/sfall/mechanize3 seems more active to me. It looks like the author patched it to be python3 compatible.