# Accessing a web page with basic auth on python

Tags: python, mechanize, basic-authentication

I'm trying to connect a web page with mechanize but I'm getting a http 401 error.

Here's my code;

```
import base64, mechanize

url = "http://www.dogus.edu.tr/dusor/FrmMain.aspx"
user = "user"
pwd = "pwd"

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

br.add_password(url, user, pwd)
#br.addheaders.append(('Authorization', 'Basic %s' % base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (user, pwd))))
print br.open(url).read()
```

Both `add_password` and `addheaders` are not working. Is it because I never specified a realm? How can I get what realm is that web page using? The username and password that I'm using are correct, as I can login using chrome with those credentials.

Comment: I was able to run your code as-is to access a page that required HTTP basic auth.

Comment: Yeah but that code isn't working for that page. Probably it's a problem with the realm, and if it's something else what am i missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The site you are using as a sample page requires the [NTLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTLM) authentication. You can see this by looking at the returned HEADER fields. For example `curl -I  http://www.dogus.edu.tr/dusor/FrmMain.aspx` returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Length: 1293
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 07 Apr 2014 21:24:09 GMT
```

The line `WWW-Authenticate: NTLM` says, which authentication method is used. I think the answer to this question [Use python mechanize to log into pages with NTLM authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22224840/use-python-mechanize-to-log-into-pages-with-ntlm-authentication) will help you.