# How to "patch" _response.py in Mechanize

Tags: python, mechanize, patch, mechanize-python

I had a issue with ntlm authentication and mechanize. After going through the below post i understood that i need to modify the _response.py file of mechanize.

[Use python mechanize to log into pages with NTLM authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22224840/use-python-mechanize-to-log-into-pages-with-ntlm-authentication)

But i am not sure where the file location is. All i could find is the .egg file for mechanize present at the location: C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages

Can someone please explain it to me how the patching is done.
Am i supposed to edit the file inside the egg file?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

- I removed the .egg file already present in the location C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages.
- Then i edited the _response.py present inside the zip which is downloaded to install Mechanize.
- Then i installed mechanize again.
- To verify i opened the .egg file and checked the _reponse.py file.